# Sentence Link UI

Tags: usability, website-design, buttons

Trying to include links in sentence form to remove "learn more" links. Should the whole sentence be the link or just the "view all" part in the sentence?

[image: Option1]

[image: Option2]

Comment: While the answer below is good, to address just the question you posed I would say make the whole line a link.

Comment: Thanks @LukeSawczak!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go the other way, and try making it *even shorter*.

Links imply that something will be viewed or visited.

[image]

Since you have a list, if it's grouped properly, you can probably drop 'for this retailer'. You could probably drop the 'All', since *dates* is plural.

If need be, you can break into cards:

[image]

You go from 8 words to 3 words, and two styles (gray and link), to just one.